# How to assign the correct type to an item interface that imports a fontawesome icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I have an `angular 11` project in development that uses `angular-fontawesome` and `angular material icon`. It contains a *'problem'* model with an optional 'icon' property: string;'. The data constant *"problem "* contains an arrangement of several *"problem "* in whose property "icon": is a string, for example "donate", that refers to the *"faDonate"* icon imported from the `fontawesome` library.

My code:

**comun.module.ts**: common module that imports `angular material icon` and `fontawesome`

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
...
// FontAwesome
import {
  FontAwesomeModule,
  FaIconLibrary,
} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {
  faBars,
  faDonate,
  …
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
…
export class ComunModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIcons(
      faBars,
      faDonate,
...
```

**problemas.model.ts**

```
export interface Problema {
  id: number;
  grupo: string;
  idgrupo: number;
  subgrupo?: string;
  titulo: string;
  encabezado?: string;
  frase: string;
  icon?: string;
  ley: string;
  parrafounotitulo?: string;
  parrafounoparrafo?: string;
  parrafounoimg?: string;
  parrafodostitulo?: string;
  parrafodosparrafo?: string;
  parrafodosimg?: string;
  parrafotrestitulo?: string;
  parrafotresparrafo?: string;
  parrafotresimg?: string;
  parrafotablaa1?: string;
  parrafotablaa2?: string;
  parrafotablab1?: string;
  parrafotablab2?: string;
  parrafotablac1?: string;
  parrafotablac2?: string;
  parrafotablad1?: string;
  parrafotablad2?: string;
}
```

**problema.component.html**

```
<div class="mostrando">
      <mat-chip-list aria-label="Icono">
        <mat-chip>
          <h4>{{ "problemas.problemas.icon" | transloco }}:</h4>
          <mat-icon><fa-icon icon="{{ problema.icon }}"></fa-icon></mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

**problema.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  OnDestroy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// import { untilDestroyed } from 'ngx-take-until-destroy';
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ANIMACIONES_RUTA_ELEMENTOS } from 'src/app/nucleo/nucleo.module';

import { ProblemasQuery } from 'src/app/pages/problemas/state/problemas.query';
import { ProblemasService } from 'src/app/pages/problemas/state/problemas.service';

@UntilDestroy()
@Component({
  selector: 'bab-problema',
  templateUrl: './problema.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./problema.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ProblemaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  rutaAnimacionesElementos = ANIMACIONES_RUTA_ELEMENTOS;
  problema$ = this.problemasQuery.selectEntity(this.problemaId);

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private problemasQuery: ProblemasQuery,
    private problemasService: ProblemasService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params) => params.get('id')),
      filter((id) => !this.problemasQuery.hasEntity(id)),
      untilDestroyed(this),
      switchMap((id) => this.problemasService.getProblemaPorId(id))
    );
  }

  get problemaId(): any {
    return this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}
```

**problemas.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProblemasService {
  filtrosProblemas: AkitaFiltersPlugin<ProblemasState>;

  constructor(
    private problemasStore: ProblemasStore,
    private problemasQuery: ProblemasQuery
  ) {
    this.filtrosProblemas = new AkitaFiltersPlugin<ProblemasState>(
      this.problemasQuery
    );
  }

  get(): Observable<Problema[]> {
    return timer(500).pipe(mapTo(problemas));
  }

  getProblemas(): Observable<Problema[]> {
    const request$ = this.get().pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        this.problemasStore.set(resp);
      })
    );

    const requestUpdate$ = this.get().pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        this.problemasStore.remove();
        this.problemasStore.set(resp);
      })
    );

    return this.problemasQuery.getHasCache() === false
      ? request$
      : requestUpdate$;

    // return request$;
  }

  getProblemaPorId(id: any): Observable<any> {
    const problema = problemas.find((current) => current.id === id);

    return timer(500).pipe(
      mapTo(problema),
      map(() => this.problemasStore.add(problema))
    );
  }
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.22.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "^2.20.0",
    "@ngneat/transloco-locale": "^1.4.0",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "^8.0.3",
    "akita-filters-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "browser-detect": "^0.2.28",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
...
```

**package-lock.json**

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": {
      "version": "0.8.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/-/angular-fontawesome-0.8.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dNmtFb/LTYWLNRfkKgCFwxgtQslNZLwUC+u7lkVAcIcjirIG6J9Ff0evl+9zR4DXFAkP0PN4RKe14NVDP3rUWA==",
      "requires": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.3"
      }
    },
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": {
      "version": "0.2.34",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/-/fontawesome-common-types-0.2.34.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XcIn3iYbTEzGIxD0/dY5+4f019jIcEIWBiHc3KrmK/ROahwxmZ/s+tdj97p/5K0klz4zZUiMfUlYP0ajhSJjmA=="
    },
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": {
      "version": "5.15.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/-/fontawesome-free-5.15.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7l/AX41m609L/EXI9EKH3Vs3v0iA8tKlIOGtw+kgcoanI7p+e4I4GYLqW3UXWiTnjSFymKSmTTPKYrivzbxxqA=="
    },
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": {
      "version": "1.2.34",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/-/fontawesome-svg-core-1.2.34.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-0KNN0nc5eIzaJxlv43QcDmTkDY1CqeN6J7OCGSs+fwGPdtv0yOQqRjieopBCmw+yd7uD3N2HeNL3Zm5isDleLg==",
      "requires": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.34"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": {
          "version": "0.2.34",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/-/fontawesome-common-types-0.2.34.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-XcIn3iYbTEzGIxD0/dY5+4f019jIcEIWBiHc3KrmK/ROahwxmZ/s+tdj97p/5K0klz4zZUiMfUlYP0ajhSJjmA=="
        }
      }
    },
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": {
      "version": "5.15.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/-/free-brands-svg-icons-5.15.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YPlVjE1cEO+OJ9I9ay3TQ3I88+XkxMTYwnnddqAboxLhPNGncsHV0DjWOVLCyuAY66yPfyndWwVn4v7vuqsO1g==",
      "requires": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.34"
      }
    },
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": {
      "version": "5.15.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/-/free-solid-svg-icons-5.15.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZfCU+QjaFsdNZmOGmfqEWhzI3JOe37x5dF4kz9GeXvKn/sTxhqMtZ7mh3lBf76SvcYY5/GKFuyG7p1r4iWMQqw==",
      "requires": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.34"
      }
    },
...
```

When compiling the app the icon looks and works, but it throws the *error TS2322 Type ‘string’ is not assignable to Type ‘IconProp’*:
[image: error TS2322]

However, the icon is perfectly visible when the app manages to launch with "ng serve":
[image: the icon is displayed]

What I have tried without it working:

1. Switch to `"strict" = false;` in *compilerOptions* in
   *tsconfig.json*.
2. Read the instructions for angular-fontawesome in its [official documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).
3. Import * IconProp *, and others like * IconName *, from `@fortawesome / fontawesome-svg-core` and assign it to the optional property `"icon ?: string;"`:

   - `“icon?: IconProp;”`
   - `“icon?: IconProp | string;”`
   - `“icon?: IconProp | IconName | string;”`
4. Install `”@ fortawesome / fontawesome-common-types":"^ 0.2.34"` and set all libraries `@fortawesome/*` with the same version of `fontawesome-common-types`, as advised by this [issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/125#issuecomment-466036515)
5. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then run `npm i @ fortawesome / fontawesome-svg-core --save` and `npm install` following this [issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/12575#issuecomment-672274516)

I thank you in advance for all the invaluable help that you can give me. Thank you.

**UPDATE: the solution to the problem.**

I found the problem in setting `angularCompilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` with the option of `"strictTemplates ": true` which enables `strict mode`.

According to the official [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) when [`strictTemplates`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates) is true what we do is enable the strict checking of the template type, which is only available with Ivy since angular version 9 and later.

The strict mode already failed me when I used the [**agm library**](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) for the web app maps, so I have disabled `strictTemplates`. So I disabled strict templates and the compile error no longer appears. This seems to be the only solution, since I have no alternative to the parameter *"icon?: string;"*, which is of type *IconProp*, and at the same time combining it with the angular interpolation in the html template.

Comment: `“icon?: IconProp;”` or `“icon?: IconName;”` should work. Do you get a different error if you use one of them?

Comment: Not working. I've tried it. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? The type of the property is [`IconProp`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/38c999e72e23c096f2938c5151a942e1df1d4f02/src/lib/icon/icon.component.ts#L37), so you need the same or compatible type. This should work unless something else is at play here (`strictNullChecks` maybe?), but it is impossible to say unless you provide an error message.

Comment: The compile-time error message is `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to Type 'IconProp'`. Is it possible that the problem comes from improperly using the angular compilation options or is it not recommended?. Thanks @yaroslav

Comment: Are you sure that `problema` property in the component actually has type `Problema`? Can you show how you declare it? From the (same) error, it looks like changing the type of the `icon` property in the interface didn't affect the component property.

Comment: "Is it possible that the problem comes from improperly using the angular compilation options or is it not recommended?" I don't think this is the case. Looks more like there is a typing issue in your component.

Comment: Or maybe @Mary Obiagba was actually right and `{{ problema.icon }}` started to erase the type and you should actually use `[icon]="problema.icon"`. I would be rather surprised if this turns out to be the case!

Comment: Yes it is. I have modified the question by adding `problem.component.ts` and `problems.service.ts`. Using `akita`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `akita` and can't traverse what is coming from where in the code unfortunately. But to give you a simple check. When you `Ctrl/Cmd + hover` over `icon` in `"{{ problema.icon }}"` it should say that it's typed as `IconProp`. If it is not, then types are not flowing correctly and you'll need to debug it, otherwise try `[icon]="problema.icon"`. And if it still does not work, then something beyond my understanding is at play here.

Comment: @yaroslav You were right. There was something else going on here (StrictNullChecks maybe?), As I had the `angularCompilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` with the option of  `"strictTemplates ": true`. Thank you. I proceed to answer in case the mistake made serves others.

Comment: Disabling the strict mode fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @babiloni did u solve this issue?

Comment: @babiloni did u solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

haven't used these icons before but have you tried referencing it in the HTML without the {{ }} ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I've tried everything, I think. With prefix, without prefix ... I even created a component for the icon.

Comment: If you go on the official site, you'll see that you can copy-paste the icon HTML code https://fontawesome.com/icons/users?style=regular

Comment: For example:.<i class="far fa-users"></i>

Answer (score 0):

the best way to bind string as font awesome icon

1- you must add this package [@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types)

2- in your .ts file add this

```
import {IconName} from `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`

const myIcon = 'user' as IconName
```

3- in your HTML file add this

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', myIcon]" ></fa-icon>
```

notice: use font awesome for angular from [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use it in the way font awesome suggest, with  tag:

```
 <span >
            <i [ngClass]="['fas', 'fa-' + data.icon]"></i>

          </span>
```

Comment: Sorry but the icon is not showing. This is the official angular component margin form for Font Awesome 5 [angular-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#angular-fontawesome)