# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RouterDirection' - Ionic 6 - angular

Tags: angular, ionic6

I'm trying to recreate my Ionic 5 app with the last Ionic 6 but I'm getting this error and I dont understand what is the problem or what keywords I should use to search about it since 'RouterDirection' is a string. I already try to search combinations of the words of the output error but could not find anything helpful for my case.
Any help?
Thank you!

My JS:

```
   appPages = [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            icon: 'home',
            url: '/private/dashboard',
            direction: 'root',
        },
        {
            title: 'Password',
            icon: 'key',
            url: '/private/user-password',
            direction: 'forward',
        }
    ];
```

My html:

```
<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages" menu="main-content-menu">
    <ion-item [routerDirection]="p.direction" [routerLink]="p.url" routerLinkActive="ion-item-active">
        <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" class="ion-margin-end"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{p.title}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-menu-toggle>
```

The ERROR:

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RouterDirection'

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, just disable this warnings in the tsconfig.json file as described in this post:
[How to assign the correct type to an item interface that imports a fontawesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822101/how-to-assign-the-correct-type-to-an-item-interface-that-imports-a-fontawesome-i)

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
```